# How to disable the Timepicker in Android

Tags: android, timepicker

I have a TimePicker in my layout.
I need to disable the TimePicker (user cannot change hours or minutes) by clicking on buttons or events.

How can I disable it?

The below snippet did not work

```
TimePicker tp = (...)findViewById(...);

  for(int i = 0; i< tp.getChildCount(); i++)
        ((View)tp.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Doesn't ``tp.setEnabled(false)`` do what you're after?

Comment: No. tp.setEnabled(false) does not work. It only disable the AM, PM button but it does not disable the hours and minutes wheels.

Comment: Are you testing this on certain device or emulator? On SGS 2 ``TimerPicker.setEnabled(false)`` disabled the whole TimePicker.

Comment: I am testing on Sony Erricson Xperia P (2.3.7). did not work

Comment: I have just tested on HTS desire HD (ISC) and it worked.

Comment: did you make it work for other devices?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea by any means but if `TimePicker.setEnabled(false)` does not work you could try recursive disabling;

```
private void disable(ViewGroup vg)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); ++i)
    {
        View v = vg.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup)
        {
            disable((ViewGroup)v);
        }
        else
        {
            v.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Just pass TimePicker to this method.

Comment: Still does not work on my Xperia P. Only the AM, PM is disabled, I can change the hour and minute

Comment: Is there any other option rather than TimePicker that allows you to pick an hour and a minute?

Comment: Not that I know - native options that is. But Android Wheel looks rather promising for this purpose;  http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < timePickerStartingHour.getChildCount(); i++) {
     Log.i("MyApp", timePickerStartingHour.getChildAt(i).getClass().getName()); //prints LinearLayout

     for (int j = 0; j < ((LinearLayout)timePickerStartingHour.getChildAt(i)).getChildCount(); j++ ) {
         ((LinearLayout)timePickerStartingHour.getChildAt(i)).getChildAt(j).setEnabled(false);
     }

 }
```

The TimePicker only has one child which is a LinearLayout, so you can't disable that, you have to disable the views that are inside the LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

```
    sButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (sButton.isChecked()) {

                timePicker.setEnabled(true);
                timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
                displayTime.setText(currentTime());
                changeTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        displayTime.setText(currentTime());
                    }
                });


            } else {
                timePicker.setEnabled(false);

            }
        }
    });
```